How to deal with begin group and end group tokens in \peek_analysis_map_inline:n?
I have already figured out that I need to do the check for the opening brace before the other checks.
But now I have the problem that \peek_analysis_map_inline:n removes the begin group token from the input stream so TeX only reads the next token as argument of \changelog_add_arg:n instead of all tokens until the corresponding end group token. I have tried to reinsert the begin group token with \c_group_begin_token but it is not treated as begin group token.
In the end I want to parse - at the beginning of a line (i.e. after a space token) to start a new \item in an itemize.
But for now I am just trying to not break commands by iterating over the tokens in the environment.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newenvironment{changelog}{%
    \changelog_parse:
}{%
}

\bool_new:N \l_changelog_in_list_bool
\bool_new:N \l_changelog_last_space_bool
\tl_new:N \l_changelog_function_call_tl
\cs_new:Nn \changelog_parse: {
    \peek_analysis_map_inline:n {
        \tl_show:n{token: ##1, charcode: ##2, catcode: "##3}
        \tl_if_eq:nnTF {##3} {1} {
            % it's an opening brace
            \def\BG{##1}\show\BG
            \peek_analysis_map_break:n{\changelog_add_arg:n \c_group_begin_token}
        }{\tl_if_eq:neTF {\end} {##1} {
            \def\END{##1}\show\END
            \changelog_call_function:
            \peek_analysis_map_break:n{##1}
        }{\int_compare:nNnTF {##2} = {-1} {
            % character code = -1 means it's a control sequence
            \def\CS{##1}\show\CS
            \tl_put_right:Ne \l_changelog_function_call_tl {##1}
        }{
            \def\ELSE{##1}\show\ELSE
            % it's something else
            \changelog_call_function:
            ##1
        }}}
    }
}

\cs_new:Nn\changelog_add_arg:n {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_changelog_function_call_tl {{#1}}
    \show\l_changelog_function_call_tl
    \changelog_parse:
}
\cs_new:Nn\changelog_call_function: {
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_changelog_function_call_tl {
        \tl_show:n{inserting~and~clearing~\l_changelog_function_call_tl}
        \l_changelog_function_call_tl
        \tl_clear:N \l_changelog_function_call_tl
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\section{Change log}
\begin{changelog}
- abc \emph{whatever}
- def
- ghi
\end{changelog}
\end{document}


I have solved what I wanted to achieve with a different approach but that does not answer my question how to use \peek_analysis_map_inline:n.
I have redefined the end of line character (^^M) to look ahead what comes next.
If the next token is a hyphen it starts a new item.
If the next token is another end of line character it starts a new paragraph.
Otherwise it inserts a space.
The implementation assumes that no line starts with an opening brace.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_changelog_in_list_bool

\cs_new:Nn \changelog_item: {
    \bool_if:NF \l_changelog_in_list_bool {
        \bool_set_true:N \l_changelog_in_list_bool
        \begin{itemize}
    }
    \item
}

\cs_new:Nn \changelog_end: {
    \bool_if:NT \l_changelog_in_list_bool {
        \end{itemize}
        \bool_set_false:N \l_changelog_in_list_bool
    }
}

\cctab_begin:N \c_code_cctab
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M%
\newenvironment{changelog}{%
    \catcode`\^^M=\active%
    \def^^M##1{%
        \ifx -##1%
            \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn%
        \else
            \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn%
        \fi%
            {\changelog_item:}%
        {\ifx ^^M##1%
            \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn%
        \else
            \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn%
        \fi%
            {\changelog_end:}%
            {~##1}%
        }
    }%
}{%
    \changelog_end:
}%
\cctab_end:%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{changelog}
New features:
    - abc \emph{whatever}
    - def
    - ghi

Bugfixes:
    - jkl
    - mno
\end{changelog}
\end{document}


I don’t want to be picky, but if you say that the above is not an answer to your question, you should probably not post it as an answer, but maybe rather as an edit … but this is for you to decide.

@JasperHabicht yeah, I was wondering about that as well. But it does not seem appropriate to add it to the question, either. Nevertheless I think it might help others to see an alternative.
